# How can i extract field name and values on a form easily

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am in need of parsing field name and values from an html form to add to my db. I know i can go and do a find
"input name='" then start another find to find the closing "'" and get the data via mid function then do the same 
for value via find "value='"
I was wondering if there is an easier way to loop the doc and extract all input names and the associated values ?

Below is a sample of what my page to parse looks like

```
    <input name='a_glare' value='B' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_testani' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_tksig' value='EC' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='2' maxlength='2'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_sacnon' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_ot' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_ovlp' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'>
```

Comment: The easier way is to submit the form first.

Comment: That's not an option, the form sits on a different server and is used to submit orders to a partner. Since they remove orders older then 30 days I need a way to archive these orders. The only way to do this is to open vendors website, bring up my order and then use the source page of the page to extract parse out my data. Once I have that figured out completely I will write a task to go login automatically and bring up the page. But I can not submit the page since it is not running on my server

Comment: So you are talking about screen scraping. You could pull the html content via cfhttp, then parse it out with something like [JSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+JSOUP). That is probably a better approach than using regexs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parsing html, I would recommend using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) instead of regular expressions. I just started using JSoup and found it extremely simple to use. Just download the jar and add it to [your application class path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).

I am not an expert by any means, but was able to print all of the "input" fields from your sample html page using this snippet:

```
<cfscript>
    // parse html string into document
    jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
    doc = jsoup.parse( yourHTMLContentString );

    // grab all "input" fields
    fields = doc.select("input");

    for (elem in fields) {
        // get attributes of each field
        fieldName = elem.attr("name");
        fieldValue = elem.attr("value");
        fieldType = elem.attr("type");

        // display values
        WriteOutput("<br>type: "& fieldType 
              &" name: "& fieldName 
              &" value: "& fieldValue
        );
    }

</cfscript>
```

(.. and yes, despite your moniker, I *am* suggesting "JSoup4You" )

---

**Update:**

The `fields` variable is an array. So you can loop through it in cfml the same way. It seems like double work, but if you prefer, you can extract the input names and values into your own array of structures (or whatever CF construct you like). For example:

```
// initialize storage array
yourArray = [];

for (elem in fields) {

    // extract field properties into a structure 
    data = { name=elem.attr("name")
            , value=elem.attr("value")
            , type=elem.attr("type")
    };

    // store in array
    arrayAppend(yourArray, data);
}

// display array contents
WriteDump(yourArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working the best so far. Easy to install and and syntax is straight forward. My problem is cfscript. How can I put those fields in an Array/Structure which I can then access via my regular coldfusion code ? something like this but in cfscript section <code><cfset keys = {}>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(fieldnames)#" index="index">
  <cfset keys[rereplace(fieldnames[index], "name='|'", "", "all")] = rereplace(fieldvalues[index], "value='|'", "", "all")>
</cfloop><code>

Comment: **Edit** Well fields is an array. Just an array of objects instead of structures. So you can use it in cfml loop the same way ie `<cfloop array="#fields#" index="elem">....` If you prefer, you could certainly generate your own array of structures, but I am not sure you really need it. See my updated response.

Comment: *RE: <cfset keys = {}>* If your end goal is a structure, rather than an array of structures, the code is not that different. Just be sure to account for multiple fields with the same "name". BTW - cfscript is just personal personal preference. IMO it is cleaner. But all of the examples above could be done in cfml.

Comment: Had to laugh at JSoup4you

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing it using two regular expressions to get the field names and field values. This is what I came up with using your example HTML.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
    <input name='a_glare' value='B' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_testani' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_tksig' value='EC' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='2' maxlength='2'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_sacnon' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_ot' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</td> 
<td align="center"> 
    <input name='a_ovlp' value='' class='inputbox-highlighted-false' size='1' maxlength='1'> 
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- extract the fieldnames and field values attributes --->
<cfset fieldnames = rematch("name='[a-z_]+'", foo)>
<cfset fieldvalues = rematch("value='[^']*'", foo)>

<!--- extract the values and build a struct of fieldname : value --->
<cfset keys = {}>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(fieldnames)#" index="index">
  <cfset keys[rereplace(fieldnames[index], "name='|'", "", "all")] = rereplace(fieldvalues[index], "value='|'", "", "all")>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#keys#">
```

Comment: This is pretty good. I retracted my answer. If I may, the only thing I might suggest is accounting for " and (shudder) lack of quotes. `<Cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"(name|value)\s*=\s*(""([^""]*)""|([^""'>\s]+[\s>]))","\1='\3\4'","ALL")>`, since I can easily see others finding this answer useful. (Of course

Comment: yup - good thoughts. I see you are also accounting for potential spaces which is also worth doing.

Comment: ok, I tried the code and got quite some strange results. It seems the code parses the field names just fine but the value part in the structure does not match the field name. Then if I use the 

<Cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"(name|value)\s*=\s*(""([^""]*)""|([^""'>\s]+[\s>]))","\1='\‌​3\4'","ALL")>  after I set foo initially I get complete crapshoot of data like "\â€Œâ€‹3" and many values don't match the field either.

Comment: To make this a bit simpler I enclosed a complete sample file which I am trying to parse  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpyxui7m63c8e2o/sampleASR.txt?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any other form fields in your HTML or a field that does not have a value attribute? Would be interesting to know if the array length of fieldvalues is the same length as your fieldnames array. The code works with the sample HTML you provided so must be something unknown in your real HTML.

Comment: Yes there are some other form fields like hidden ones etc, I posted a link of a full sample page which should give you a good idea as what kind of fields there might be

Comment: Right, that makes it more interesting :) I see you have things like `<select name="xyz"><option value="option1>Option 1</option><option value="option2">Option 2</option></select>` Not sure which value you'd want for field xyz as there is more than one potential value. I think you're going to have to grab all the input boxes and iterate using something like `<cfset fields = rematch("<input[^>]+>", foo)>` and do the same for the select boxes and pull out whichever value you need but it's going to be painful I'm afraid.

Comment: Lets assume I don't care for any of the select stuff is there a way to make this happen that name and values match up ?

Comment: `<cfset fields = rematch("<input[^>]+>", foo)>` will grab all the input form fields so that'll get you started. I did also notice that you have several `form` tags in that page so I could see a situation where two forms have the same field name with different values causing you issues. As a result you may need to firstly grab the form by name and then filter from there.

Comment: @NoSoup4you If I may, the easiest route is the remove the select from the html all together `<cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"(<select[^>]*>[^]*?</select>","","ALL") />` and as far as values not aligning, you can replace inputs without a value attribute with a blank value attribute, *deep breath*. `<cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"<input\s(?!([^>]*)name='[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+'([^>]*)value='[^']*'([^>]*)>|([^>]*)value='[^']*'([^>]*)name='[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+'([^>]*)>)","<input value='' ","ALL")>`

Answer (score 0):

Well here's one idea that may not be any better than simply regexing out every thing.

1) Add a closing slash to each of your input values so they look like so:

```
   <input name='a_ot' 
                        value='' 
                        class='inputbox-highlighted-false'
                        size='1'
                        maxlength='1'/>
```

2) extract the whole table starting with the `<table>` tag and ending with the `</table>` tag.

3) Parse the table into an XML object using XMLParse as in:

Now you have an XML object with an array of TD tages each of which would have an INPUT child with attributes of name and value. You could use cfdump and loop code to extract or clean it up.

Again, this may not save you any time depending on how messy the HTML is and how hard you have to work to figure out the XML. Good luck.