# coldfusion loop over file not working quite right

Tags: loops, coldfusion

In ColdFusion I am creating and saving a file, then later looping over characters in the file to display part of it.  This is almost working, but the loop is sometimes inserting characters that are formatting rather than just the output.  And sometimes it is losing the formatting. Here are the original and the version as read:

[image: created-read]

The code:

```
<cfset colvalue = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('#col#')>
<cfset repa = colvalue[1]>
<cfloop file="#reppath#moxrep/#repa#.cfm" index="chunk" characters="500"> 
<cfoutput>#chunk#</cfoutput><br> 
</cfloop>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code?  Is there a bug in the ColdFusion loop over file?  And if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but .. Why use getParameterValues() instead of the URL scope? Also, if the file stores plain HTML, why use a .cfm extension?

Comment: I am not any kind of coldfusion expert, and was very glad to find the getParameterValues which gives me an accurate array of what I am passing (unlike form.xxx).  To use the URL scope wouldn't I have to pass the values via URL?  And I believe that is limited in how much I can pass, is that correct?

Comment: Re the .cfm extension, I  had no idea what was actually in those files until I started trying to retrieve part and had to look at them.  I didn't realize there was no coldfusion in them until just now when you pointed it out.  How would I be sure there never would be coldfusion tags in such files?  I am using a cfsavecontent to create the output and a cffile to put it away.  There are plenty of coldfusion tags in the program that creates the cfsavecontent.

Comment: Sorry, it was late when I posted. I meant one of the standard in scopes ie URL, FORM, REQUEST, etcetera. Technically, there is nothing wrong with using `getPageContext()`. However, since CF exposes most values in a system scope, it is normally not neccessary.  *I am using a cfsavecontent to create the output and a cffile to put it away* Well I have no idea what is in the files, but if the content is strictly HTML, there is no reason to save it as .cfm.  Use .htm|.html.

Answer (score 1):

> `<cfloop .. characters="500">`

It is because your loop uses the "characters" attribute, which limits the number of characters ["..read during each iteration of the loop.."](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfloop%3A+looping+over+a+list%2C+a+file%2C+or+an+array). That would be fine for a text file. However, since the file content is HTML, it breaks when you try and insert the `<br>` at an arbitrary position. That causes part of the HTML code to be displayed instead of rendered. For example:

```
<div <br> style="text-align: left; ">This will not render correctly</div>
```

That said, it begs the question why read the content line by line instead of just displaying the whole file?

**Update:**

You really cannot parse HTML with basic string functions or regular expressions - not with any reliability. Encountering a new line character does not necessarily mean you have reached the end of a particular block of HTML code. It is perfectly valid for an HTML element to span multiple lines. Plus, HTML elements are frequently nested. So it is near impossible to identify the "logical" endpoints using string functions (which is basically what the cfloop is doing) alone.

Instead, I would recommend [using a tool like JSOUP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939531/104223) which is specifically designed for parsing HTML. Once you have parsed the document, it is very easy to access specific elements or sections of the HTML.

Comment: After playing around with the file to be read, I found that removing the <br> tags wasn't sufficient.  I played around removing other white space, and eventually got a proper rendition of the output.  But there is no obvious pattern to it.  For example , if I have a proper rendition and add or subtract a blank line, it becomes wrong again.  The actual output may run hundreds of pages, so I don't want to retrieve the whole file unless the user specifically requests it.  If he is just looking around to find the right report, a page or two ought to be sufficient.  Any further suggestions welcome.

Comment: Hi Leigh,  I appreciate this explanation and the links as well.  Nowhere did I find documentation explaining how the loop over a file works. Before I tackle jsoup I'm going to see whether I can create a short test file along with each report.  That way I can use <cffile  to read the whole test report when they want a peek.  You said jsoup has to read the entire file, and since some of my files are likely to be very big, that doesn't seem efficient.  Or do you think it ismore iefficient than <cffile?  If so, maybe that is the route I should take? for everything.

Comment: Leigh, You know, <cffile isn't doing a very good job anyway, adding all sorts of blank lines to my files,  so if you think jsoup is a better approach I will try it out.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well you cannot achieve what you are trying to do with basic looping and string functions. So you have to use something else. IIRC, there are buffering options you can use to help with memory if needed, but get it working first. Then worry about performance and efficiency.

Comment: *documentation explaining how the loop over a file works* It reads a single line from the file until the EOF is reached.  Lines are usually denoted by a line feed and/or carriage return characters ie chr(10) and chr(13).

Comment: Hi Leigh,  I knew that much.  But it doesn't actually produce the lines it reads -- renders the output of the HTML.  And not very well.  So the documentation I couldn't find should say that, and recommend this method only for genuine text files.

Comment: Re get it working and then worry about performance, that is generally good advice.   What I worry about is getting way down the road with some approach and then discovering I cannot make it work adequately for large files.  If I knew coldfusion better, I could know when to worry and when not to.  I'm going to try creating a preview file, and use cffile to let the user look at that.  The coding problems that involves are easy to solve (although somewhat annoying) and I know it will work.

Comment: Well, the way to find out is to run some tests.  *creating a preview file, and use cffile to let the user look at that* Why do you need to generate a file? Why not just dump it to the screen or generate a download (if appropriate)?

Comment: Hi Leigh,  I do send it to a screen, and save it if requested.  I suppose I could download it if requested.  The reports are not fixed, they are generated very dynamically -- i.e. the user can request anything he wants.   I think they might want to look at a report and revise it without having to toggle between their own computer and my system.  But you raise a good point -- I'll think it through.  Thanks.